# Block comments in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a quite long gnuplot script. For debugging purposes, I would like to be able to block comment parts of this script or use a "goto" statement. Is this possible?

I know I can use an `if` statement:

```
if (1 == 2) {
commented-out-code
} else {
non-commented-out code
}
```

Is this the only solution?

Comment: it's also usable for real block comments. Because Gnuplot *interprets* the text, most elements are syntactically tolerated ([see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33956570/2932052)).

Answer (score 8):

Comments in gnuplot start with a `#`. If you want to comment a whole block, your text editor should be able to do that (e.g. <kbd>M-;</kbd> in Emacs with the block selected).

Answer (score 6):

Gnuplot doesn't support block comments ([as of version 5](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf#section*.12)). But since Gnuplot *interprets* your script, the solution you gave does the job. But instead of using an expression to be falsified (evaluated to `0`), use a maximally obvious notation (for safety add a comment for its purpose). **Spare the `else` block** as it's noting but complicating things.

Look on the following example, to see that it's not as easy as one might think.

```
if (0) { # commented-out block
This block is completely ignored by Gnuplot.
Well, obviously not completely...
# }{
...because Gnuplot is not just looking for the closing curly brace ;-)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution to the one proposed by @choroba is to separate the parts of the script into different files, then manage a "master" file that calls the ones you haven't commented:

```
# master script
load "part1.plt"
#load "part2.plt"
load "part3.plt"
```