# Can I put comments into long plot commands?

Tags: gnuplot

My gnuplot plot command is

```
tM=1.0*(a0*xmax+ymax)
set parametric
set trange [-0.2:tM]
plot  1/0,1/0 title '\ict\qquad' lc rgb 'gray80' dt 5 lw 2,\
uldx0(t),uldy0(t) title '\disct' lc rgb 'web-green' lw 3,\
hpx0(t),hpy0(t) lc rgb 'pink'  lw 2,\
 vpx0(t),vpy0(t) with filledcurve xy= 0.5*(xmi0+xpl0),0\
 fs transparent solid 0.25 fc rgb 'cyan' ,\
for [n=1:5] ix0(n*0.05+t*n*0.005/tM ,u0(0,n*0.05)),\
iy0(n*0.05+t*n*0.005/tM,u0(0,n*0.05))\
 lc rgb 'gray80' dt 5 lw 2,\
for [n=6:10] ix0(n*0.05+t*n*0.01/tM ,u0(0,n*0.05)),\
iy0(n*0.05+t*n*0.01/tM,u0(0,n*0.05))\
 lc rgb 'gray80' dt 5 lw 2,\
  for [n=22:36] ix0(n*0.025+t ,u0(0,n*0.025)),\
iy0(n*0.025+t,u0(0,n*0.025))\
lc rgb 'gray80' dt 5 lw 2,\
x0(t*pmax0(q1)/tM,q1), y0(t*pmax0(q1)/tM,q1)  \
 lc rgb q1color lw 2,\
x0(t*pmax0(ql0)/tM,ql0),  y0(t*pmax0(ql0)/tM,ql0)  \
 lc rgb qlcolor lw 2,\
x0(t*pmax0(QqxyL0)/tM,QqxyL0), y0(t*pmax0(QqxyL0)/tM,QqxyL0)  \
 lc rgb qhatmicolor lw 2,\
x0(t*pmax0(q2)/tM,q2) ,  y0(t*pmax0(q2)/tM,q2)  \
 lc rgb q2color lw 2,\
x0(t*pmax0(qpl0)/tM,qpl0), y0(t*pmax0(qpl0)/tM,qpl0)   \
 lc rgb qplcolor lw 2,\
x0(t*pmax0(QqxyR0)/tM,QqxyR0), y0(t*pmax0(QqxyR0)/tM,QqxyR0)  \
 lc rgb qhatplcolor lw 2
```

Is there a good way to break this up with comments which would also help may should I decide to look at this later?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Block comments in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050498/block-comments-in-gnuplot)

Comment: I could not get it to work within the plot command. Probably I could use block comments  elsewhere in the script. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All inside a single `plot` command, right?
I think the closest is to take advantage of the fact that each clause of a plot command can start with a definition.  The intended use is something like `plot a=2 x**a`, but you could pick some junk variable and assign it to a comment string

```
plot \
    _c="Straight line" x   title _c, \
    _c="Parabola" x**2     title 'x^2', \
    _c="Some weird function" real(sinh(sqrt(x))) title 'squint(x)'
```

If you like you can use that comment string in the plot title, which is something close to the originally intended use. But also you can just ignore it in the plot clause.  It would then only be relevant to someone reading the source, not to the output from the plot command.

Comment: Thank you, I did have to do a bit more before the "for" command in the plot, it was necessary to put in a dummy plot so the comment was c1='%Indifference curves' 1/0,1/0, \